# Flutter disposing large no of TextEdititingController

Tags: flutter, dispose, texteditingcontroller

I have no of TextEditingController a, TextEditingController b.......z

1)
How to short cut way dispose all TextEditingController

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    // _nameCtrl.dispose();
    a.dispose();
    b.dispose();
     .....
     ....
    z.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

2. if don't dispose the TextEditingControll var , will it caused problem ?

thanks
Wing

try to simplify and shorten codee

Comment: dispose means you are Clean up the controller when the widget is removed from the widget tree.

Answer (score 0):

as per my knowledge:

> `dispose` means that you are Clean up the `controller` when the widget is
> removed from the widget tree. So when tree are rebuild, eg: you are
> calling `setState` the widget tree will rebuild, and because you
> already `dispose` all the controller, they will not consume any memory
> since they are not exist in the widget tree.

Answer (score 0):

Well according to a great article on the internet :

> If you create objects and do not free the memory used by them before
> their destruction, there will be chances your application will through
> a memory leakage in the app store or the play store. It is the exit
> point of the Stateful Widget. Execution of dispose method is done in
> the end when the state object had built itself enough times and now
> there is no need for it to build again.

Which means that it is a good practice to always dispose off all your controllers as they can cause an issue later on.

And as for your shortcut then why don't you use a for loop iterating over a list containing all the controller names that you've used in your Stateful widget:

```
List tec = [a,b,c,d...z];
for(var element in tec) {
  element.dispose();
}
```